# Reinstall conan requires from conanfile.py

Tags: conan

Can I somehow automatically specify in conanfile.py install the required package even if it is already installed?
If I do `conan install <package>` with my hands, then it will install it, even if it was installed before. But in conanfile.py it just writes ": Already installed!" and goes on.

This may `conan create <package> --<param>`, but it would be better if it was written in the recipe itself.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you need that? Are your packages corrupted? There is no re-install option because packages are checked based on its checksum, so it's guaranteed that is working since first installation. Now, if you want to update you local cache, you use `--update`, or even `--build` to build all packages from source again. The complete reference: https://docs.conan.io/en/latest/reference/commands/consumer/install.html

Comment: @uilianries I install packages with a relative installation path, because they are a kind of components for other components to work, but they should also participate in compiling the current package. 
And because of the specifics of the project requirements, I need to get a completely identical build of the project in at least 5 minutes, at least in 10 years. I know that if I overwrite the package in conan with the same name, the end result will change, but these are administrative tasks, not mine